# Coldfusion websocket cant create a websocket handshake while changing ws to wss protocol

Tags: javascript, iis, websocket, coldfusion, coldfusion-2018

Coldfusion websocket (using `cfwebsocket` with secure attribute true) cant create a websocket handshake, I am getting a connection refused error. To make websocket secure I followed these steps but I am getting
Error in connection establishment: `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` in network WS tab

- Administrator. Administrator console > Server Setting > WebSocket: Enabled  SSL Port
- Added secure attribute true for `cfwebsocket` tag

Comment: could you please share which kind of certificate you are using(self - signed or purchased one)? which port you are using as a connector? please share the full error message.

Comment: Self-signed JKS file created using java keytool.

Comment: @AnanthakrishnanBaji Please check your SSL port number and web socket port number is enabled in your firewall